# javascript, Google Chrome treats alert call from input and html buttons differently

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, alert

I created a form to be processed with javascript only (no submit) and found that Google Chrome was erasing all the inputs when I popped up an alert. After some experimenting, I found that Chrome behaves differently depending on whether the javascript alert is called from button element or an input element. In particular, the HTML button causes the text in the input box to be deleted when you click OK. This does not happen in IE. I have not tried it in other browsers. It does not happen with the input element, and it does not happen with the button element if it is outside the form.

Has anyone else noticed this, or know of a reason why it should be so?

```
<form>
<p>Enter some text in the input box, then click one of the buttons.</p>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="alert('What happens to form values?')" value="Input button">    <br>
<button onclick="alert('What happens to form values?')">HTML button</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` is submitting the form when clicked.
Submitting the form reloads the page.

To prevent this, add `return false` to the end of the handler.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't think my code was formatted correctly in my initial post. I edited it, and I think it's okay now.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't think my code was formatted correctly in my initial post. I edited it, and I think it's okay now. Do you mean add to the onclick code, as onclick="alert('...');return false" ? I see that the button handler causes the page to reload, but only in Chrome, and adding "return false" after the call to alert doesn't seem to change that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

based on w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

> Always specify the type attribute for the  element. Different browsers may use different default types for the  element.

in your case you want the type to be `button` (otherwise some browsers will default to `submit`)

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert('What happens to form values?')">HTML button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks-- that explains it. Apparently, the default type for the button element in Google Chrome is reset, but it's button in IE.